# Macbook sees Japanese keyboard instead of native US English

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac, keyboard

Mavericks on Macbook Pro Retina A1398 (US keyboard with horizontal Enter) shows Japanese keyboard (JIS, with vertical Enter) on enabled keyboard viewer. How do I make Mavericks to recognize and to show its native US Keyboard layout?
I have tried to reset SMC and PRAM with no success.
p.s. I have tried changing input sources to U.S. as well - does not change the orientation of return on bluish keyboard on the right - mac OS still thinks I have JIS...

Comment: Does keyboard viewer show the topmost leftmost character key to be a 1?  If not, what?

Comment: It shows 1 in the top left corner...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your machine is not recognizing the "keyboard type" correctly, thinking you have a JIS (or ISO) type instead of ANSI.   See this article for some suggestions on fixing it:

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Thank you, Tom! You've got it. Unfortunately Mavericks do not have spatial file suggested in the article no more and I've tried reseting PRAM and SMC already with no effect. I think it is something to do with internal keyboard marking since mac stubbornly sees JIS instead of ANSI...

Comment: Did you try the  Terminal Command?

Comment: Yes, Tom! OS recognizes my ANSI as JIS. So it finds no issues. *2015-02-22 20:57:25.351 KeyboardSetupAssistant[659:507] No unknown keyboard connected - terminating
logout
*

Comment: I am afraid that I have to replace the topcase and that will take forever...

Comment: Similar issue, but with external keyboard... http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1582071

Comment: No solution, except replacing the thing...

Comment: Please include the essence of the linked article in your answer. If the link target should go away, this would render your answer useless.

Comment: Everything just backs to normal after I install Karabiner. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources tab and click the "+" key to add the US Keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Icon. That does not change the orientation of the Return key. I do actually use U.S. input source already. Even then the keyboard viewer shows layout vertical enter as it probably thinks that I might have actual Japanese keyboard, which is nonsense. I am trying to understand how to change the way OSX thinks about my actual keyboard....